# Trying to set up API Management REST API Authentication w/ Node JS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, azure, azure-api-management

My goal is to authenticate a Node.js client w/ the Azure API Management API.

I am struggling a bit here with the translating this C# example to Node.js Javascript. I've tested the C# example with my own id and key and it seems to authenticate `200` with the API, but I keep getting a `401` with my Node.js snippet.

I have a feeling that it may have to do with the way that the C# example formats the expiry (`ex={1:o}`) which is a type of [Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip)

## C# Example

source: [Azure API Management REST API Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication)

```cs
using System;   
using System.Text;   
using System.Globalization;   
using System.Security.Cryptography;   

public class Program   
{   
    public static void Main()   
    {   
        var id = "12345678abcdefgh";   
        var key = "1234abcd5678asdf==";   
        var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10);   
        using (var encoder = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))   
        {   
            var dataToSign = id + "\n" + expiry.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   
            var hash = encoder.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign));   
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);   
            var encodedToken = string.Format("SharedAccessSignature uid={0}&ex={1:o}&sn={2}", id, expiry, signature);   
            Console.WriteLine(encodedToken);   
        }   
    }   
}
```

## My Node.js Snippet

```js
var util = require('util')
var crypto = require('crypto')
var generateAccessCode = function() {
    var id = "1234asdf1234asdf";
    var key = "1234asdf1234ghjk";
    const accessCodeExpireDays = 10;
    const formatString = 'SharedAccessSignature uid=%s&ex=%s&sn=%s'
    const dataToSignString = '%s\n%s';

    //create expiry string
    var today = new Date();
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(today.getDate() + accessCodeExpireDays);
    expiry = expiry.toISOString();

    //create hash
    var dataToSign = util.format(dataToSignString, id, expiry)
    const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key)
        .update(dataToSign)
        .digest('base64');

    var encodedToken = util.format(formatString, id, expiry, hash);

    console.log(encodedToken)
}

generateAccessCode()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to format the expiry date as below via [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/):

```
//create expiry string
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date();
expiry.setDate(today.getDate() + accessCodeExpireDays);
expiry = moment(expiry).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS[Z]')
```

Comment: That was it, Thanks Aaron!